# Javascript - Converting total Minutes into Days, Hours and Minutes without using Math.Floor

Tags: javascript

I am having total Minutes and i want to convert that total minutes into number of Days, Hours and Minutes format.

```
var duration = getControlValue('incident','incident_open_duration');
var formattedDuration = duration/24/60 + ":" + duration/60%24 + ':' + duration%60);
alert(formattedDuration);
```

If the total minutes is 8289.66 , the above line of code returns `5.756708333333333:18.161:9.659999999999854`

I don't need decimals, i want to eliminate and round off them so i used `Math.floor(time/24/60) + ":" + Math.floor(time/60%24) + ':' + Math.floor(time%60)` but unfortunately my tool is not supporting Math.floor function

Do we have any other way of achieving this ?

Comment: Hi @ns046  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double [Bitwise_NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

```js
var duration = 8289.66;
var cleanDuration = ~~(duration / 24 / 60) + ":" + ~~(duration / 60 % 24) + ':' + ~~(duration % 60);
console.log(cleanDuration);
//Suggested by @STh format if you need a format like HH:mm:ss
var formattedDuration = String(~~(duration / 24 / 60)).padStart(2, '0') + ":" + String(~~(duration / 60 % 24)).padStart(2, '0') + ':' + String(~~(duration % 60)).padStart(2, '0')

console.log(formattedDuration);
```

The snippet above adds leading zeros if the hours / minutes / seconds are only one digit via the [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method.

Another alternative is [Left_shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift), [Right_shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift) or [Unsigned right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift) with 0

```js
var duration = 8289.66;
var formattedDuration = ((duration / 24 / 60) << 0) + ":" + ((duration / 60 % 24) << 0) + ':' + ((duration % 60) << 0);
console.log("Left Shift Example" , formattedDuration);

var formattedDuration = ((duration / 24 / 60) >> 0) + ":" + ((duration / 60 % 24) >> 0) + ':' + ((duration % 60) >> 0);
console.log("Rigth Shift Example" , formattedDuration);

var formattedDuration = ((duration / 24 / 60) >>> 0) + ":" + ((duration / 60 % 24) >>> 0) + ':' + ((duration % 60) >>> 0);
console.log("Unsigned right shift Example" , formattedDuration);
```

Or [Bitwise_OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) with 0

```js
var duration = 8289.66;
var formattedDuration = ((duration / 24 / 60)|0) + ":" + ((duration / 60 % 24)|0) + ':' + ((duration % 60)|0)

console.log(formattedDuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are the [GET Dates](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) method, with which you can extract the components from a date. If you only have the duration, you can, e.g., use the `new Date(duration_in_ms)` constructor.

So, to fit your use case, the code is:

```js
const x = new Date(duration * 60 * 1000).getXXX()
```

where `getXXX` is one of the GET Dates-methods.